# Time-align perceived onsets of vocal samples

Tags: daw, sound-editing, reaper, samples

I have a homemade library of sung-word samples that I need to time align, such that the onset of the first vowel (i.e. the pitched part) is a fixed time distance from the beginning of the sample.

As a concrete example, imagine the words "eat", "feet", and "fleet" being sung.  If I were to synthesize a track of straight eighth notes from these samples, the "ee"s should be evenly spaced.  Since "fleet" has the longest initial consonants, all the other samples would need to be delayed such that their "ee" sounds align with that of "fleet."

An example of an orchestral library that does what I'm after is Audio Imperial Nucleus, where instruments with a fast attack are actually delayed so that during playback, they sound simultaneously with instruments that have a slower attack.  Thus you can write music as it should sound, without needing to offset tracks afterward.

I can do this with my samples through a combination of "by ear" and "by sight", but I wondered: **is there a better workflow or automated tool that could achieve what I'm after?**  If I could, in bulk, detect and add a marker to the pitched/vowel part of the sound, I could move each sample onto its own track, line up the onset points, and then add silence to the beginning of the shorter samples.

PS: If this would be better in a different SOS forum, Mods please feel free to move it over.

PPS: If it makes a difference, I'm a Reaper user, though not opposed to other tools if they make this chore easier!

Comment: It might be worth a look at [VocAlign](https://www.synchroarts.com). It's not a purpose I've ever tried using it for, but that's kind of part of its job.